# Bottom div is overlapping the top

Tags: html, css

I am running into a bit of trouble trying to get the mid section content div to appear under the top div. What I mean is that the bottom div is overlapping and appearing underneath, or on the bottom of, the top div.

Here are two images and the code to give you a better idea of what I am trying to write:

Here is what it looks like in browser:
[image]

Here is what it should look like:
[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="topBar">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--top left phone number and icon start-->
       <div id="leftTop">
            <div id="facebookTop">
            <a href="#">
            <img src="images/facebook-icon.png" alt="GreatOrlandoDiscounts Become our friend on Facebook!" />
            </a>
            </div>
            <p class="topLeftNumber">Call us at: <mark class="orange">1-800-544-7646</mark></p>
        </div>
        <!--top left phone number and icon end-->
                <!--top right phone number and icon start-->
                <div id="rightTop">
                <div id="twitterTop">
                <img src="images/twitter-icon.png" alt="GreatOrlandoDiscounts Follow us on Twitter" />
                </div>
                <p class="topRightNumber">Call us at: <mark class="orange">1-800-544-7646</mark></p>
                </div> 
                <!--top left phone number and icon end-->
                    <!--Left nav bar start-->
                    <div id="leftNavBar">
                        <!--left nav dropdown start-->
                        <div id="navBarLeft">
                        <div id="dropdownContainerLeft">
                        <div id="menuLeft">
                        <ul>
                        <li class="home"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com">HOME</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/orlando-attractions.html">THEME PARKS</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/walt-disney-world.htm">Disney</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/universal-orlando.htm">Universal Studios</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/sea-world-orlando.htm">SeaWorld</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/busch-gardens-tickets.htm">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/dinner-shows.html">Dinner Shows</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/orlando-attractions.html">WATER PARKS</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/walt-disney-world.htm">Disney</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/universal-orlando.htm">Universal Studios</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/sea-world-orlando.htm">SeaWorld</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/busch-gardens-tickets.htm">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/dinner-shows.html">Dinner Shows</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--left nav dropdown end-->
                    </div>
                    <!--Left nav bar end-->
                    <!--Right nav bar start-->
                    <div id="rightNavBar">
                    <!--Right nav dropdown start-->
                        <div id="navBarRight">
                        <div id="dropdownContainerRight">
                        <div id="menuRight">
                        <ul>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/orlando-attractions.html">DINNER SHOWS</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/walt-disney-world.htm">Disney</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/universal-orlando.htm">Universal Studios</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/sea-world-orlando.htm">SeaWorld</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/busch-gardens-tickets.htm">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/dinner-shows.html">Dinner Shows</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/orlando-attractions.html">ATTRACTIONS</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/walt-disney-world.htm">Disney</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/universal-orlando.htm">Universal Studios</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/sea-world-orlando.htm">SeaWorld</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/busch-gardens-tickets.htm">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/dinner-shows.html">Dinner Shows</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/orlando-attractions.html">SERVICES</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/walt-disney-world.htm">Disney</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/universal-orlando.htm">Universal Studios</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/sea-world-orlando.htm">SeaWorld</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/busch-gardens-tickets.htm">Busch Gardens</a></li>
                        <li class="attractions"><a href="http://www.ticketmomma.com/dinner-shows.html">Dinner Shows</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Right nav dropdown end-->
                    </div>
                    <!--Right nav bar end-->
                        <!--Main image start - ONLY CHANGE IMAGE IN INLINE CODE-->
                         <div id="mainImage">
                         <img class="main" src="images/main-image.jpg"  alt="Discount Walt Disney World Tickets" />
                         </div>
                         <!--Main image end-->
                                <!--Logo start-->
                                <div id="logo">
                                <a href="http://www.greatorlandodiscounts.com">
                                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Great Orlando Discount Tickets" />
                                </a>
                                </div>  
                                <!--Logo end--> 
      </div>
</div> 
<!--Middle section start-->
        <div id="midSecWrapper">
            <!--midSpacer start-->
            <div id="midSpacer"></div>
            <!--midSpacer end-->
        </div>
<!--Middle section end-->

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image:url(../images/body-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
}

#topBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    background-image:url(../images/top-bar.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    position: relative;
    z-index:0;  
}

#wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    height: 501px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
    width: 260px;
    height: 185px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftTop {
    width: 350px;
    height: 58px;
    float: left;
    z-index:200;
}

#rightTop {
    width: 360px;
    height: 58px;
    float: right;
    z-index:300;
}

#mainImage {
    width: 980px;
    height: 401px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -100;
    margin-top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    top: -2px;
}

#facebookTop {
    float:left;
    margin: 4px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#twitterTop {
    float:right;
    margin: 4px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#leftNavBar {
    width: 340px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    z-index:600;
}

#rightNavBar {
    width: 360px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    z-index:700;
}

#midSecWrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    height: 501px;
}

#midSpacer {
    width: 980px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image:url(../images/spacer.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.topLeftNumber {
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #e1ebf4;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.topRightNumber {
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #e1ebf4;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align:right;
}

mark.orange {
    color:#fa7252;
    background: none;
}

.twitterTop {
}

/*Nav bar style left*/
#menuLeft {
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0;
}
#menuLeft ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#menuLeft li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#menuLeft li a{
    font-size: 12px;
    width:110px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #9d9d9d;
    color: #454f54;
}

#menuLeft li a:hover{ 
    background-image: url(../images/nav-hover-bg.jpg); 
    color: #fa7252; background-color: #e1ebf4;
}

#menuLeft ul ul{ 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    background-color: #e1ebf4; 
    color: #22293c;
}

#menuLeft ul li:hover ul{ 
    visibility:visible; 
    color: #22293c; 
}
/*Nav Bar Style left end*/

/*Nav bar style right*/
#menuRight {
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0;
}
#menuRight ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#menuRight li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#menuRight li a{
    font-size: 12px;
    width:120px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #9d9d9d;
    color: #454f54;
}

#menuRight li a:hover{ 
    background-image: url(../images/nav-hover-bg.jpg); 
    color: #fff; background-color: #e1ebf4;
}

#menuRight ul ul{ 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 30px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    background-color: #e1ebf4; 
    color: #22293c;
}

#menuRight ul li:hover ul{ 
    visibility:visible; 
    color: #22293c; 
}
/*Nav Bar Style right end*/
```

Comment: Coul you please comment your code to point the part where the problem happens?

Comment: Thank you! If you look at the <!--Middle section start-->, that is where the middle section div starts to appear at the top of the page, instead of under the top div. If you look in the image, you can see a line in the nav bar. It is supposed to be underneath the big main image.

Comment: You should definitely test vico's answer. I thought the issue was with the logo and not that image.

Comment: So, put the logo display: block?

Comment: They're by default `inline-block`, so they work a little bit different than `block`. But is the issue with the logo or with your `midSpacer`??

Comment: i think that it is with my midSpacer. That div is inside the midSecWrapper that I will be using for my main content.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the `midSpacer` that shows in the middle and not under the `topBar` right?

Comment: Yes. There are going to be 3 main divs, wrapper, midSecWrapper and the footer. I thought I could put them on one another without overlapping. I have done this before, but not with positioning and z-index.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not set

clear:both;
so the bar is floating up

if you can provide the url then i can tell you exactly which/where to add

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, it is not live yet. I am working locally and testing it out on various browsers before I go live.

Answer (score 0):

I see you set the top's bar position as relative but *relative to what?*: you dont't specify a top, left, right nor a bottom relative amount. Also, you should set your `midSecWrapper`'s `clear` property to `both`:

```
#topBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
    background-image:url(../images/top-bar.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    /* position: relative; */
    z-index:0;  
    float: left;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    height: 501px;
    /* position:relative; */
    z-index:100;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

#midSecWrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    height: 501px;
    clear: both;
}
```

You can test it with [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/35GL2/).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I plug the code in and I get the same result. I kind of knew I would have a problem trying to use positioning and the z-index, but I have to try and I would like to use my design as is. I may have to re-design... Basically, there are going to be 3 main divs, wrapper, midSecWrapper and the footer. I figure I could stack, for lack of a better term, on one another without overlapping. I have done this before, but not with positioning and z-index.

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry, the `clear` property must be set for the `midSecWrapper` (it's who's clearing the space). Also, if you use floats you should set specific heights and widths, and the container of the floats must also be "floated".

Comment: Thank you so much! I plugged in the code and the midSecWrapper looks like it went behind the main image. I have heights and widths set to specifics. So, I would have to float the wrapper and the midSecWrapper?

Comment: Yes, they must be floated according to the whole page in order for the renderer to work well. So if the children are floated, the parent must be floated too, all the way up to the ultimate parent (the one just inside the `body` element).

Comment: If I float the wrapper to the left or right, the entire thing does in that direction.

Comment: Of course, you should then center it manually by specifying a `left` margin.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but could you instruct me how to do that if I want everything centered?

Comment: The only way I could get it to work is by setting the padding-top: 400px; on the midSecWrapper. I could not get it to drop down below the main #wrapper for anything. Do you think that will be alright? I mean, is it bad form/code?

Comment: It's okay, but I suggest you use margins, because padding is space added *inside* the element and margins are space added *outside* of it. Also, you can use google chrome's analizer to know where are your elements and the css and metrics associated to them, open it by pressing F12.

Comment: Thanks! Can I still add the top margin even if I have it set to margin:0 auto? I just don't know way that div will not drop below the top one.

Comment: The you should set your margin like this: `margin: 400px 0px 0px 0px` or specifying only the top margin with `margin-top: 400px`.

Comment: Will that take away the center, though?

Comment: You should then specify the left and right margins as `auto` in the shorthand mode: `margin: 400px auto 0px auto` or each one individually with `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`.

Comment: I was actually able to make it work by putting a #wrapperContainer around the entire top div. I set it like this:

wrapperContainer {
margin: 0 auto;
width:100%;
height:505px;
}

That contained all of the elements and allowed me to drop the midSecWrapper in place under the image.
Is that good, or good code, or is there a "right way" to do it? I always assumed that if the site functions the way I want it to and it validates, it is good to go.

Comment: I was actually able to make it work by putting a #wrapperContainer around the entire top div. I set it like this:

wrapperContainer {
margin: 0 auto;
width:100%;
height:505px;
}

That contained all of the elements and allowed me to drop the midSecWrapper in place under the image.
Is that good, or good code, or is there a "right way" to do it? I always assumed that if the site functions the way I want it to and it validates, it is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in the comment section, but I thought I would post it as an answer. I may be a solution and possibly help someone else out with a similar problem.

I was actually able to make it work by putting a #wrapperContainer around the entire top div. I set it like this:

```
wrapperContainer {
margin: 0 auto;
width:100%;
height:505px;
}
```

That contained all of the elements and allowed me to drop the midSecWrapper in place under the image.
Is that good, or good code, or is there a "right way" to do it? I always assumed that if the site functions the way I want it to and it validates, it is good to go.